# Converting a winrt::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock object to C++/CX object

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I am porting my project from C++/CX to C++/WinRT. For this I need to do some interop stuff like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx.

Microsoft recommends using helper functions like these for interoperability.

> from_cx and to_cx functions
> The helper function below converts a C++/CX object to an equivalent C++/WinRT object. The function casts a C++/CX object to its underlying IUnknown interface pointer. It then calls QueryInterface on that pointer to query for the default interface of the C++/WinRT object. QueryInterface is the Windows Runtime application binary interface (ABI) equivalent of the C++/CX safe_cast extension. And, the winrt::put_abi function retrieves the address of a C++/WinRT object's underlying IUnknown interface pointer so that it can be set to another value.

```
template <typename T>
T from_cx(Platform::Object^ from)
{
    T to{ nullptr };

    winrt::check_hresult(reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown*>(from)
        ->QueryInterface(winrt::guid_of<T>(),
            reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(to))));

    return to;
}
```

> The helper function below converts a C++/WinRT object to an equivalent
> C++/CX object. The winrt::get_abi function retrieves a pointer to a
> C++/WinRT object's underlying IUnknown interface. The function casts
> that pointer to a C++/CX object before using the C++/CX safe_cast
> extension to query for the requested C++/CX type.

```
template <typename T>
T^ to_cx(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown const& from)
{
    return safe_cast<T^>(reinterpret_cast<Platform::Object^>(winrt::get_abi(from)));
}
```

But, when I do something like this:

```
auto text = winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock();
Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^ cx = to_cx<Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^>(text);
```

I get an error:

> No instance of function template "to_cx" matches the argument list

> Argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI:: Xanl::Controls::TextBlock)

But I do see that TextBlock inherits from IUnknown. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Converting a winrt::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock object to C++/CX object

If you want to [port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx#porting-strategies) a **C++/WinRT** object to a **C++/CX** object. You could make Windows Runtime Component(**C++/WinRT**) project for the solution and put the converting code in it. Then make the **C++/WinRT** project refer the
above Component (Right click the **C++/WinRT** project name int the Solution Explorer, click  Add, choose References, select the component name you just added under Projects in the Add Reference dialog).

**Note**

You need to use [Consume Windows Runtime Extension>Yes(/ZM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx#example-project-showing-the-two-helper-functions-in-use) in the  Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT) project instead of the C++/WinRT project.

Then, in the  Windows Runtime Component(**C++/WinRT**), add cx namespace and winrt namespace to distinct the different object using different language.

The following code can be put into your component project’s class.

**Add the needed headers such as:**

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>

In the cx namespace, add  using statements:
namespace cx
{
    using namespace Windows::Foundation;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
}

// And, in the winrt namespace, add the needed using statements:

namespace winrt
{
    using namespace Windows;
    using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Core;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
    using namespace Windows::UI;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
    using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
    using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;
}
Add the to_cx method:
template <typename T>
T^ to_cx(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown const& from)
{
    return safe_cast<T^>(reinterpret_cast<Platform::Object^>(winrt::get_abi(from)));
}

//Change the code:

/*auto text = winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock();
Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^ cx = to_cx<Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement^>(text);*/

auto text = winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock();
        cx::FrameworkElement^ cx = to_cx<cx::FrameworkElement>(text);
```

### Please note :

Please don't put the converting code into a XAML page, because your XAML page types need to be ether entirely C++/CX or
Entirely C++/WinRT. You can mix C++/CX and C++/WinRT outside of XAML page types within the same project.

The function which uses the converting code in the component project’s class must be declared in the class’s [idl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro) file first, or we can not reference the function in another project.

**Update:**

Here is a simple [sample](https://github.com/wcj233/WinrtTest) I created, when clicked the button in the main project, I called the method of Windows Runtime Component to trigger the to_cx method, you can check it.

Comment: But i still get this error: No instance of function template "to_cx" matches the argument list

Argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI:: Xanml::Controls::TextBlock)

Comment: We have upload code sample. please check the case update part.

Comment: also for from_cx i get an error like this: 


"error C2664: 'HRESULT IUnknown::QueryInterface(const IID &,void **)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const winrt::guid' to 'const IID &' 
note: Reason: cannot convert from 'const winrt::guid' to 'const IID'
note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called"


Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: The conversion operators between winrt::guid and IID rely on the definition of IID being available before C++/WinRT is included. In practical terms, you need to #include <unknwn.h> or <inspectable.h> before you #include any C++/WinRT headers.